# Linear Regression without using R

Tags: php, linear-regression

I have a task which requires to generate the slope and interception of two sets of data by linear regression. According to the following link, it can be easily accomplished by R:

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/linear-regression-R

The codes are simply like

```
model <- lm(sales ~ youtube, data = marketing)
```

However, I will need to implement it in PHP. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can do such operation easily in R.
But since you said you have to do it this time in PHP. You may use the following function:

```
<?php

function linear_regression($x, $y) {
  // calculate number points
  $n = count($x);
  
  // ensure both arrays of points are the same size
  if ($n != count($y)) {

    trigger_error("linear_regression(): Number of elements in coordinate arrays do not match.", E_USER_ERROR);
  
  }

  // calculate sums
  $x_sum = array_sum($x);
  $y_sum = array_sum($y);

  $xx_sum = 0;
  $xy_sum = 0;
  
  for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
  
    $xy_sum+=($x[$i]*$y[$i]);
    $xx_sum+=($x[$i]*$x[$i]);
    
  }
    // calculate slope
  $m = (($n * $xy_sum) - ($x_sum * $y_sum)) / (($n * $xx_sum) - ($x_sum * $x_sum));
  
  // calculate intercept
  $b = ($y_sum - ($m * $x_sum)) / $n;
    
  // return result
  return array("m"=>$m, "b"=>$b);
}
?>
```

As an example, you may use the following codes to get the slope and intercept of the two sets of data:

```
$a=array();
$b=array();

array_push($a,$adata1);
array_push($a,$adata2);
array_push($a,$adata3);
array_push($a,$adata4);

array_push($b,$bdata1);
array_push($b,$bdata2);
array_push($b,$bdata3);
array_push($b,$bdata4);


$aa= linear_regression($a, $b);

$slope1= $aa["m"]; 
$intercept1= $aa["b"];
```